# Hiding Excel behind UserForm when UserForm moves

Tags: vba, excel

I want to hide the excel file behind the `Userform`.

Is it possible that when I move the `Userform` with cursor, then Excel application behind the `UserForm` also moves?

Answer (score 2):

The application has properties you can define

- Top
- Left
- Width
- Height

used like:

```
Application.Top = 0
```

Play around with this in various events in the userform until you find what youre after.

I strongly suggest learning how to capture the userform's values and then assigning them to the application.

Answer (score 1):

Extending the answer by @DougCoats - its important to set the `Application.WindowState` to `xlNormal` in order to manipulate `Application` properties such as `Top` and `Left` etc. See the code below - you need to include a `Module` and `UserForm` in your workbook:

### Module1

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestForm()

    UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

### UserForm1

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    HideApplicationBehindUserForm
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Layout()
    HideApplicationBehindUserForm
End Sub

Private Sub HideApplicationBehindUserForm()
    With Application
        .WindowState = xlNormal
        .Top = Me.Top
        .Left = Me.Left
        .Height = Me.Height
        .Width = Me.Width
    End With
End Sub
```

The `Initialize` event will hide the Excel application behind the `UserForm` when you open it. The `Layout` event will move the application behind the `UserForm` when you move the `UserForm` around with your mouse. The code is the same in both circumstances - `HideApplicationBehindUserForm`.

I see a little problem with my Excel where the application is slightly off to the border of the `UserForm`:[image]

Comment: I tend to leave them with some work when they didnt bother to read the rules/google/research at all. I like being helpful but I am also kind of a sadist LOL

Comment: @DougCoats - lol, I know what you mean but couldn't resist ;)

Comment: *I see a little problem with my Excel where the application is slightly off to the border of the UserForm* - not the only problem you're going to encounter trying to hide the fact that VBA is *hosted* by a *host application*; IMO OP is trying to make a hosted VBA "application" look like a standalone app - i.e. wrong tool for the job. Make a real standalone WinForms app if you want something that looks like a standalone WinForms app.